# execute function according to obj key

Tags: javascript

```
function a() {
     console.log('a');
}

function b() {
     console.log('b');
}

function c() {
     console.log('c');
}

let obj1 = {a:1}
let obj2 = {a:1, c:1}
let obj3 = {b:1, c:2}
```

Is this possible, write some code to execute function according to `obj1 obj2 obj3` key?

example1 `obj`1  then execute `function a()`

example2 `obj2`  then execeute `function a()` and `function c()`

example3 `obj3`  then execute  `function  b()`  and  `function  c()`

I saw some package always create new object and pass an object in second parameter.

ex:  `let test = new B('test', { a: 10, b: 20  });`
 (  B is a class )

It seen like execute something base on object key.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? It looks to me like you are asking for `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here (barring more context that might suggest a completely different approach) is to put those functions in an object or Map, and then use the property name as a key into that object or map to make the call:

```js
const functions = {
    a() {
        console.log('a');
    },
    b() {
        console.log('b');
    },
    c() {
        console.log('c');
    }
};

let obj1 = {a:1};
let obj2 = {a:1, c:1};
let obj3 = {b:1, c:2};

function callForObj(label, obj) {
    console.log(label);
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        functions[key]();
    }
}

callForObj("obj1:", obj1);
callForObj("obj2:", obj2);
callForObj("obj3:", obj3);
```

That uses `Object.keys` and is based purely on the object having a property with that key (ignoring the value). If you want to take values into account, use `Object.entries` instead, perhaps with destructuring:

```
function callForObj(label, obj) {
    console.log(label);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value) {
            functions[key]();
        }
    }
}
```

```js
const functions = {
    a() {
        console.log('a');
    },
    b() {
        console.log('b');
    },
    c() {
        console.log('c');
    }
};

let obj1 = {a:1};
let obj2 = {a:1, c:1};
let obj3 = {b:1, c:2};

function callForObj(label, obj) {
    console.log(label);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value) {
            functions[key]();
        }
    }
}

callForObj("obj1:", obj1);
callForObj("obj2:", obj2);
callForObj("obj3:", obj3);
```

---

Note: If the order of the calls is important, I'd suggest using an array rather than an object. Even though ES2015 adds order to object properties, and ES2020 requires that `Object.keys` and `entries` and `for-in` follow it (which ES2015 didn't), it's still fragile because for non-index-named properties, it depends on the order in which they were created:

```js
console.log(Object.keys({a: 1, b: 2})); // ["a", "b"]
console.log(Object.keys({b: 2, a: 1})); // ["b", "a"]
```

Comment: But this doesn't guarantee that `a` is called before `c`, because objects don't guarantee order, do they?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. It seems the order does not matter.

Comment: @schroffl - Ah, that's a good point, I didn't really twig to order being important in the question (I can read it both ways). Objects **do** have order now (as of ES2015), even for older operations like `Object.keys` (as of ES2020), so in a modern JavaScript engine the above **is** guaranteed to call `a` before `c`. But using that order is rarely useful or appropriate; better to use an array if order is important.

Comment: @schroffl [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties). For questions on property order, there is hardly a thing that's not worth reading in there.

Comment: @ASDFGerte - Oriol's answer to that question is out of date now. (Depending on how pedantic you want to be, since the question is "Does **ES6** introduce..." :-) ES2020 makes it apply even to `Object.keys` and such.)

Comment: Yes, but CertainPerformance posted just that as an answer aswell. On top of that, trincot mentions a mistake in the previous engine realizations (does he? Maybe he forgot to link, this is [the related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121521/object-keys-order-for-large-numerical-indexes)), along with a recent spec change, which is not really too relevant for normal programming, but still an interesting side fact. Luckily, for that question, there is almost no spam at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too

```js
    function a() {
         console.log('a');
    }

    function b() {
         console.log('b');
    }

    function c() {
         console.log('c');
    }

    let objectFunction = { a,b,c };
    
    objectFunction['a']();
```